# Как отрисовать промежуток между 2 датами в jqurery UI datapicker?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

```js
$.datepicker.regional.ru = {
        closeText: "Закрыть",
        prevText: "&#x3C;Пред",
        nextText: "След&#x3E;",
        currentText: "Сегодня",
        monthNames: [ "Январь","Февраль","Март","Апрель","Май","Июнь",
            "Июль","Август","Сентябрь","Октябрь","Ноябрь","Декабрь" ],
        monthNamesShort: [ "Янв","Фев","Мар","Апр","Май","Июн",
            "Июл","Авг","Сен","Окт","Ноя","Дек" ],
        dayNames: [ "воскресенье","понедельник","вторник","среда","четверг","пятница","суббота" ],
        dayNamesShort: [ "вск","пнд","втр","срд","чтв","птн","сбт" ],
        dayNamesMin: [ "Вс","Пн","Вт","Ср","Чт","Пт","Сб" ],
        weekHeader: "Нед",
        dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy",
        firstDay: 1,
        isRTL: false,
        showMonthAfterYear: false,
        yearSuffix: "" };
    $.datepicker.setDefaults( $.datepicker.regional.ru );


    $( ".datepicker-multiple" ).datepicker({
            numberOfMonths: 3,
        });
```

```css
.calendars-wrap .ui-widget.ui-widget-content {
  border: none;
}


.calendars-wrap .ui-datepicker-inline {
  width: 100% !important;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}


.calendars-wrap .calendars-wrap .ui-widget.ui-widget-content {
  border: none;
}

.calendars-wrap .ui-datepicker-multi-3 .ui-datepicker-group {

  &:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}

.calendars-wrap .datepicker-multiple .ui-widget.ui-widget-content {
  display: flex !important;
  width: 100% !important;
}

.calendars-wrap .ui-datepicker-row-break {
  display: none;
}

.calendars-wrap .ui-datepicker-multi-3 .ui-datepicker-group:nth-child(1) {
  margin-right: 48px;
}

.calendars-wrap .ui-datepicker-multi-3 .ui-datepicker-group:nth-child(2) {
  margin-right: 48px;
}


.calendars-wrap {
  margin-top: 99px;
}

.ui-widget-header {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  margin-bottom: 44px;
}

.calendars-wrap .ui-widget-header {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  margin-bottom: 44px;
}

.calendars-wrap .ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-title {
  font-family: $Roboto;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 32px;
  color: #151515;
}

.ui-datepicker th {
  font-family: $Roboto;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #9B9B9B;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  padding: 0;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(155, 155, 155, 0.3);
}

.calendars-wrap .ui-datepicker th {
  font-family: $Roboto;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #9B9B9B;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  padding: 0;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(155, 155, 155, 0.3);
}

.calendars-wrap .ui-datepicker-calendar tbody tr:first-child td {
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.ui-datepicker td {
  height: 28px;
  padding-bottom: 13px;
  background: none;
}

.calendars-wrap .ui-datepicker td {
  height: 28px;
  padding-bottom: 13px;
  background: none;
}

.ui-state-default {
  background: none !important;
  border: none !important;
  font-family: $Roboto ;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold !important;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 16px;
  color: #151515 !important;
  text-align: center !important;
}

.calendars-wrap .ui-state-default {
  background: none !important;
  border: none !important;
  font-family: $Roboto ;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold !important;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 16px;
  color: #151515 !important;
  text-align: center !important;
}

.calendars-wrap .ui-datepicker-today {
  position: relative;

  
}

.calendars-wrap .ui-datepicker-today:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 33%;
    left: 52%;
    transform: translate(-50%,  -50%);
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    background: #C0964C;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }

.calendars-wrap .ui-datepicker-today  a {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    color: #fff !important;
  }


/*.calendars-wrap .ui-icon-circle-triangle-w {
  display: block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-image: url('../img/al.svg') !important;
}

.calendars-wrap .ui-widget-header .ui-icon {
  background-image: url('../img/al.svg') !important;
}

.calendars-wrap .ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-prev {
  background-image: url('../img/al.svg') !important;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
}*/


.calendars-wrap .ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-prev-hover, .ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-next-hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: none;
}

.calendars-wrap .ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-next {
 /* background-image: url('../img/al.svg') !important;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;*/
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="calendars-wrap">
        <div class="datepicker-multiple"></div>
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Немного завела в тупик задача. 
Есть календарь на основе плагина UI datapicker.
На страницу он должен выводится без возможности взаимодействия с пользователем. Он нужен что бы отображать свободные даты. По моей задумке даты будут приходить из WP админки. 
Задача состоит в том, что бы взять эти даты, и на их основе нарисовать такое (c 6 по 15 мая): 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И таких дат может быть несколько и на разные месяц...
Помогите пожалуйста с этим вопросом.

Comment: `beforeShowDate` отработайте и все дела

Answer (score 2, accepted):

проверьте даты на попадание в имеющиеся интервалы (массив `ranges` в примере) с помощью события `beforeShowDate` и добавьте нужные классы. Ну и собственно переопределите стили нужным образом.

```js
const cd = new Date();
const range = [{ 
        s: new Date(cd.getFullYear(), cd.getMonth(), 5), 
        e: new Date(cd.getFullYear(), cd.getMonth(), 15)}
      ];

$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({          
  beforeShowDay: function(d){        
        let cls = range.reduce(function(cls,v){                     
                     if(d.getTime() >= v.s.getTime() && 
                        d.getTime() <= v.e.getTime()) cls.push("p-inside");
                     if(d.getTime() == v.s.getTime()) cls.push('p-start');
                     if(d.getTime() == v.e.getTime()) cls.push('p-end');
                        
                     return cls; 
                  }, []);            
        return [true, cls.join(' '), null];
     }
});
```

```css
.p-inside a { color: blue !important; }
.p-start a  { color: red !important; }
.p-end a    { color: red !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<div class="datepicker"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь!!!!!!!